# show dynamic checkboxes in order

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to show dynamic checkboxes in order (from 1 to 30) but they are appearing in the opposite order (from 30 to 1), also the number 1 is not showing when the slider reach 30:

```
for (var i = 1; i <= N; i++) {
    var $input = $('<input/>', {
      type: "checkbox",
      id: "checkbox-" + i
    });
    var $label = $('<label/>', {
      id: "label-" + i,
      for: "checkbox-" + i
    }).append(i);
    var $container = $('<div/>', {
      id: "chckContainer-" + i
    }).append($input).append($label);

    $("#showChck").append($container);
}
```

They are show/hidden based on a slider value but I'm not sure if that's the problem.

This is where they are append to:

```
<div data-role="fieldcontain" id="channels" style="display:none;">
    <fieldset id="showChck" data-role="controlgroup" data-type="horizontal">

    </fieldset>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/6vkyh4kL/5/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Couple of changes as far as I can see, along with `:gt` also add `:eq`

```
$("#showChck div").show().filter(":eq("+ui.value+"), :gt(" + (ui.value) + ")").hide();
```

Change the condition from `ui.value == 1` to `< 1`

```
if (ui.value < 1) { 
  $("#show_channels").hide();
  $("#label-1").hide();
} else {
  $("#show_channels").show();
}
```

Here is the updated demo **http://jsfiddle.net/dhirajbodicherla/6vkyh4kL/10/**

Hope this helps.

Comment: So those filters were showing them in the opposite order? I really need to learn about them and jquery. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to change `N-ui.value` to `ui.value - 1`.
No need to add any extra filters

```
$("#showChck div").show().filter(":lt(" + (ui.value - 1) + ")").hide();
```

and change `ui.value == 1` to `ui.value < 1`

```
 if (ui.value < 1) {
            $("#show_channels").hide();
            $("#label-1").hide();
        } else {
            $("#show_channels").show();
        }
```

[Fiddle1](http://jsfiddle.net/anurag_anand/ymdh23gj/1/)

**EDIT:**
To display only one box when slider is at one, and display 30 when slider is at 30.

```
$("#showChck div").show().filter(":gt(" + (ui.value - 1) + ")").hide();
```

replace `:lt` with `:gt`

[Fiddle2](http://jsfiddle.net/anurag_anand/sr8e4ppL/1/)

Comment: this is not the way OP wants it to be. When the scroll is at 30 all the 30 boxes should be visible and at 1 only the first one should be visible

Comment: @DhirajBodicherla Okay it is clear now. 
I have edited my answer.